# question about charAt function

Tags: java, algorithm

i know java API function   charAt   for example

```
String  s="dato"
  char r=s.charAt(0); r is equal d
```

but my question is how realy it works or what function  can i use instead of charAt  function to get same result?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To what purpose? I mean, if `charAt(0)` does what you want, why look for something else?

But, to answer your question: no, there is no (reasonably straight forward) way to get the n<sup>th</sup> character from a String in Java. You could use `String`'s `substring(...)` method, but that returns a `String`, not a `char`.

Or first convert your `String` into an array of `char`'s with `String`'s`toCharArray()` and get a character from the array, but that's just silly when you have `charAt(...)` at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "function", there are only methods on objects, one object class is `String`, and this class offers `charAt()` for this purpose. Note that a `String` is similar to an array of `char`s, or a sequence of chars, and retrieving a character is just accessing the correct index in that sequence.

Note that it would be possible to get the first char in other ways (like converting the string to an array or whatever), but that wouldn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The String class represents character strings. All string literals in Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this class.
Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. String buffers support mutable strings. Because String objects are immutable they can be shared. For example:

```
 String str = "abc";
```

is equivalent to:

```
 char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

**charAt**

Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0 to length() - 1. The first char value of the sequence is at index 0, the next at index 1, and so on, as for array indexing.

If the char value specified by the index is a surrogate, the surrogate value is returned.

**Specified by:**

*charAt* in interface CharSequence

**Parameters:**

*index* - the index of the char value.

**Returns:**

the char value at the specified index of this string. The first char value is at index 0.

**Throws:**

*IndexOutOfBoundsException* - if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string.